# how to make multiple api request using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

i am having exsiting service to make api call through axios in my react app,which i think is limited to one api request at a time,i wanted to make multiple request using **axios.all**,but i am not able to find way to modify the service,see below is the code

As in Action.js you can see that i combine two request which is wrong i guess so,please help me how to combine two request using axios.all,and please suggest api service implementation is correct or what can i do to improve it

> APIService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import apiConfig from './apiConfig';
import UserSession from './userSession';
import history from '../utils/history/history';

const session = sessionStorage;

var axiosConfig = axios.create({
                  baseURL: apiConfig.baseUrl,
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null ? 
                    `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` : null,
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
                timeout: 20000,
                responseType: 'json'
              });

 axiosConfig.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization =
        sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null ? `Bearer 
        ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}` : null;
    return config;
 },(error) => Promise.reject(error));

const apiService = function(options) {
 const onSuccess = function(response) {
    if (response.status === 201) {
        return Promise.resolve(
            Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    message: response.statusText
                }
            )
        );
    } else if (response.status === 200) {
        if ((response.data && response.data !== null) || response.data !== 
             undefined || response.data !== '') {
            return response.data;
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        message: response.statusText
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    } else if (response.data.length < 1) {
        return Promise.reject(
            Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    message: 'No Data'
                }
            )
        );
    } else {
        return response.data;
    }
};

const onError = function(error) {
    if (error.response) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
            window.location = '/login';
            return Promise.reject(error.response);
        } else if (error.response.status === 404) {
            return Promise.reject(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        message: error.response.statusText
                    }
                )
            );
        } else if (error.response.status === 500) {
            return Promise.reject(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        message: error.response.statusText
                    }
                )
            );
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
        }
    } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received

        return Promise.reject(
            Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    message: error.message
                }
            )
        );
        //return Promise.reject(error.message);
    } else {
        // Something else happened while setting up the request
        // triggered the error
        return Promise.reject(
            Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    message: error.message
                }
            )
        );
    }
};

return axiosConfig(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
};

export default apiService;
```

> Request.js

```
import apiService from '../apiService';

export const FirstRequest = () => {
  return apiService({
    url: 'FirstURL',
    method: 'get',
  });
};


export const SecondRequest = () => {
  return apiService({
    url: 'SecondURL',
    method: 'get',
  });
};
```

> Action.js

```
export const SomeHandler = () => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
    type: API_REQUEST
   });

 FirstRequest()
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
            type: API_SUCCESS
        });
         SecondRequest().then((res) => {
            dispatch({
              type: API_SUCCESS
            });
            dispatch({ type: VIEW1, payload: res });
          dispatch({ type: VIEW2, payload: res });
           }).catch((err) => {
           dispatch({
            type: API_FAILURE,
            payload: err
           });
        });


    })
    .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
            type: API_FAILURE,
            payload: err
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to axios at all. You can combine two async functions together in an action method, using `async` library:

```
async.parallel([
    getUsers,
    getComments
],
function(err, results) {
    // the results array will equal to [[], {'x': 'y'}] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
    // dispatch here
});

function getUsers(callback) {
    callback(null, [])
}

function getComments(callback) {
    callback(null, {'x': 'y'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, not sure you want to do this in your componentWillMount, because your component will not render until all this is done, it's better to have it in componentDidMount and have some default states that will update once done with these requests. Second, you want to limit the number of setStates you write because they might cause additional re-renders, here is a solution using async/await:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const firstRequest = await axios.get(URL1);
  const secondRequest = await axios.get(URL2);
  const thirdRequest = await axios.get(URL3);

  this.setState({
    p1Location: firstRequest.data,
    p2Location: SecondRequest.data,
    p3Location: thirdRequest.data,
  });
}
```

Comment: But i dont want to expose api url to component,they should managed in some config file and call also should separately maintained as you can see in above code

Answer (score 0):

**i'm working this way. you can use this**

```
 const token_config = {
 headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.JWD_TOKEN}`
   }
 }

const [ res1, res2 ] =  await Axios.all([
    Axios.get(`https://api-1`, token_config), 
    Axios.get(`https://api-2`, token_config)
  ]);

  res.json({
    info: {
      "res_1": res1,
      "res_2": res2
    }
  });
```